Can't Update to WSL 2 - Error 0x80041002
I recently started using WSL, and whenever I install any distro, it gives me this 0x80041002 error. So I installed Ubuntu with WSL 1, and I cannot convert to WSL 2. This is the error:
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Error: 0x80041002

I installed the distro from MS Store and it didn’t start and gave the same error code as above. So i used the —-set-version command to change to wsl 1
So my problem is that I can’t use WSL 2 at all

WSL1 has not been updated in over 3 years.  So there are no additional updates to WSL1.  The message suggests you are attempting to convert the WSL1 instance to WSL2. Is that your attention? If you are installing from the Microsoft Store then you are only installing WSL2. What command exactly did you run to install Windows Subsystem for Linux? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

@Ramhound I have edited the question. Please take a look

You didn’t Indicate how you installed WSL. Did you run the install command or do something else? The error you indicated is only caused by one particular reason documented on the install page for WSL.
